# Implementation a super User Functonality in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I want to implementation superuser functionality in my asp.net MVC project see below structure:

what my plan:

**Super User**

First I have a username and password for a superuser because of super user login the admin panel and register an administrator and manager.

**First**: when superuser registers an administrator I want to give then full authority(updator) and when superuser registers a manager then I want to give authority(only viewer).

For Example:

**1 step**: super user login then register an administrator and manager:

tblregistration

add an administrator

Filed Name:

```
first name: Suraj
last name: Bartoli
email id: ra@gcom
password: ******
image: image name
```

add a manager

Filed Name:

```
first name: Rahul
last name: Bartoli
email id: rahul@com
password: ******
image: image name
```

**2 step**: then add user roles:   tbluserroles

for ex:

Filed Name:

```
user: Suraj
role: administrator

user: Rahul
role: manager
```

**3 step**: then app/user-security: tblusersecurity

Filed Name:

```
user: Suraj
app: admin panel 
role:updator

username: Rahul
app-name: admin panel(view only whole update panel)
role: viewer
```

I hope my question is understood.

Still I M not Implement this functionality?

can anyone suggest I m going the wrong way or the right way? or anyone suggests add a new field in the table or remove filed in the table?

Comment: Take a look at [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

Answer (score 0):

**For Roles**

It seems that you have multiple roles upon which you will decide what are the privileges. I would suggest, you must have separate table like `tblRoles` which consists of following properties

```
    role_id bigint primary key,
    role_name nvarchar(200),
    role_description nvarchar(200),
    role_privilege nvarchar(200)
```

Instead of using `role names` (like updator, viewer etc.) use `role ids` as *foreign key* in other tables.

Same is with `user ids`, instead of using user names in different table

Comment: thanks for suggestion now my tblrole look like ```roleid,role_name(updator,viewer),role_description,role_previlege,username```? can u tell me one thing which value store in role_description,role_previlege?

Comment: description can be used for having additional information, it can be optional.For role privilege you can store information about the rights against role